# Python: if a variable is declared in a function can I access it's value the next time the function is called?

Tags: python, process

Python question:

I'm using Popen to start an instance of MPlayer.

The same function is used to pass commands to the process declared.

```
def mp_controller(cmd,val=""):
iput=""
if cmd=="pos":
    iput="seek "+val+" 2"
elif cmd=="open":
    mp=subprocess.Popen(["mplayer","-slave","-quiet",val],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
elif cmd=="adv":
    iput="seek "+val+" 0"
etc...etc...
```

I call the function initially passing it the path to the video file and the command "open"

Subsequently, when I pass the function the command "pos" followed the number in seconds that I wish the video to advance to, I find I get an error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mp' referenced before assignment
```

Presumably this is because the integrity of the mp variable is not maintained between function calls.

Is there a way of declaring the variable so that it is accessible on subsequent calling?

I am calling the function from a thread polling a USB device and also from a Tkinter widget set

Comment: add global keyword and define the variable in the function. It would work

Comment: @Vivs no, using mutable global state is an anti-pattern

Comment: The *very important* thing to understand is that *python doesn't have variable declarations*. Variables spring into existence when they are assigned to in whatever namespace. In any case, it *sounds* like you want something like C static variables. Python does not have that. Two common approaches to handling state in Python would be to 1) explicitly pass and return the state that you need from your function 2) use a class to encapsulate state.

Comment: At a first glance, it looks like `mp_controller` should be a class, with methods named `pos`, `open`, `adv`, etc.

Comment: @juanpa, yes, I can see that (I think I said as much in my OP). Surely there's a way to keep the instance alive, though? After all, if it was instantiated in the root namespace, it would continue to be accessible. I'm not sure how making it a class changes this behaviour.

Comment: @DaveCoventry The instance stays alive as long as it is being referred to by at least one reference. Currently, you create one reference, a local variable `mp`, which is discarded when the function terminates, and when the reference count reaches zero, the instance is reclaimed

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you're saying it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it (I'm open to correction), using a class to define my mplayer controls is under just the same restrictions as defining a function would be, that is I can't see any way of making the instantiated process available to my program.

My solution is to write a separate simple script and use that.

```
import  sys
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for line in sys.stdin:
    cmd=line[:1]
    if cmd=="q":
      break
    elif cmd=="o":
      mp = subprocess.Popen(["mplayer", "-slave", "-quiet", line[2:-1]], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    else:
      mp.stdin.write(line[:-1])
```

Only problem is that I can't send it multiple commands from the first script using `mp.stdin.write`, so, as a temporary solution, I'm writing to a FIFO file.